# Unable to deploy Next.js app 'process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c npm ci" did not complete successfully'

Tags: javascript, next.js

I recently finished developing an application on Next js (discord clone) and I wanted to deploy it to railway but I get this

```
Dockerfile:20

-------------------

18 |     ENV NIXPACKS_PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$NIXPACKS_PATH

19 |     COPY . /app/.

20 | >>> RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/f030b20a-f891-45f4-a90b-e68a001e0ab2-/root/npm,target=/root/.npm npm ci

21 |

22 |     # build phase

-------------------

ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c npm ci" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

 
Error: Docker build failed
```

I tried a lot of things but nothing helped, I decided to deploy it to the oar and it worked there, but in the developer console it shows this

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 ()
84-43d7e0f08e9f6991.js:6 
WebSocket connection to 'wss://next-js-aeternitas.vercel.app/api/socket/io?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=G3Y8vg55sZi4_TIKAAAA' failed:
```

Comment: GitHub repo https://github.com/TadevosyannGarik/NextJs-Aeternitas

Answer (score 0):

“failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c npm ci" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1” typically occurs when there is a mismatch between your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json files.

try, Update your lock file: Run npm install to update your lock file or  You can delete the package-lock.json file and then run npm i --package-lock-only to regenerate it.

Comment: No, it didn't help, same error, but thanks for your time